# Implement two restriction on textfield in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a text field in which I want to restrict it by max length and special characters. I have implemented max length which works fine but when I implement special character restriction it does not catch that condition my code is,

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
if textField == firstNameTxt
    {
        guard let textFieldText = textField.text,
            let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textFieldText) else {
                return false
        }
        let substringToReplace = textFieldText[rangeOfTextToReplace]
        let count = textFieldText.count - substringToReplace.count + string.count
        return count <= 15

    }
else if textField == firstNameTxt
    {
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"+0123456789 !@#$%^&*()_+{}[]|\"<>,.~`/:;?-=\\¥'£•¢")//Here change this characters based on your requirement
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
    }

    return true
}
```

How I can make both restrictions at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use `regex` to block the typing of unwanted characters in `UITextField`. [Regex Pattern](https://www.regextester.com/) is a best way to validate the content with maximum conditions rather than writing the logical code.

**UITextFieldDelegate:**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text,
       let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
       let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange,
                                                   with: string)
       return validateString(updatedText)
    }
    return true
}
```

**Validation:**

```
func validateString(_ string: String?) -> Bool {
    let regex = "^[a-zA-Z]{0,15}$"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
    let isValid = predicate.evaluate(with: string)
    return isValid
}
```

**Edit**

In the regex, we can mention the characters range in `{}` braces. In the given scenario we mentioned `{0,15}` as range.

To know more about regex patterns, please check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions/

Comment: This is allowing me to enter digits and comma in text field i want to restrict that. @Sateesh

Comment: @Hamza, please check now.

Comment: How we can restrict space also in that? .@Sateesh

Comment: Remove space in the regex *"^[a-zA-Z]{0,15}$"*. I have just edited the answer.

Comment: @Hamza Where is the check for count in this answer?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, Check the **Edit** in answer.

Comment: @Sateesh ah i see. I did not know you could do it like that. Nice. :)